# Discrete Random Variable vs Continuous Random Variable for statistics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am teaching the normal distribution as a continuous random variable and my students have just learned binomial distribution. Wondering what would be a good idea to explain the transition from discrete to continuous where, instead of histogram, we now find the probability as area under the curve?

Would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the mean of the binomial, some $M$, and then let $p = M/n$ and consider the sequence of distributions $$\mathcal{B}(n,p) = \mathcal{B}(n,M/n).$$

You will converge to a continuous distribution, you can show this by the sequence of pdfs.

Another way is to fix any distribution $\mathcal{D}$, even discrete, and find $$S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ where $X_k \sim \mathcal{D}$ for all $k$. Then $S_n$ will converge to the normal distribution (by the CLT).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for an introductory probability course to make the transition from discrete to continuous begins by explaining the Poisson process, first showing that the number $X_t$ of arrivals before time $t$ is so distributed that
$$
\Pr(X_t=x) = \frac{(\lambda t)^x e^{-\lambda t}}{x!}.
$$
Then let $T_x$ be the time until the $x$th arrival, and show that the two events
$$
\big[ X_t < x \big] \quad \text{and} \quad \big[ T_x >t \big]
$$
are the same event and therefore have the same probability. From this we get
$$
\Pr(T_1 > t) = \Pr(X_t =0) = e^{-\lambda t} \text{ for } t\ge0
$$
and there you have a continuous probability distribution.